# How can I do this join-table with Eloquent Relationships?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationships

## Purpose

I would like to get the total of mutual interests between all users referring to a single user, using **Eloquent Relationships** instead of **Query Builder** directly.

## Table structure

**users**

```
+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | John   |
|  2 | George |
|  3 | Paul   |
+----+--------+
```

**interests**

```
+----+-----------+
| id |   name    |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | apple     |
|  2 | banana    |
|  3 | pineapple |
+----+-----------+
```

**users_interests**

```
+--------+------------+
| userId | interestId |
+--------+------------+
|      1 |          1 |
|      1 |          2 |
|      1 |          3 |
|      2 |          1 |
|      2 |          2 |
|      3 |          1 |
+--------+------------+
```

## Example

Something like that...

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "George",
        "mutualInterests": 2,
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Paul",
        "mutualInterests": 1,
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your User model

```
public function interests()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Interest');
}
```

In your Interest model

```
public function users() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

Now in your controller function

```
$users = User::all();
```

Now in your view to get the count of all number of interest in your each users.

```
@foreach($users as $user)
         {{ $user->interests()->count() }}
         <!-- if you need to extract all interests then -->
         @foreach($user->interests as $interest)
                  {{ $interest->name }}
         @endforeach
    @endforeach
```

**An update** based on your comment to see mutual interest count too

```
@foreach($users as $user)
         {{ $user->interests()->count() }}
         <!-- if you need to extract all interests then -->
         <?php $mutualInterest= 0; ?> 
         @foreach($user->interests as $interest)
                  <?php
                        $check = checkfunction($interest->id);
                        if($check == TRUE){
                              $mutualInterest = $mutualInterest+1;
                        }

                    ?>
                  {{ $interest->name }}
         @endforeach
         <?php echo "Mutual Intersts".$mutualInterest; ?>
@endforeach
```

Now in check function at bottom of your view

```
<?php
function checkfunction($id){
    $interest = App\Interest::find($id);

    if($interest->users()->count()>1){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
In your example, I would get the total number of interests of each user separately.
But my proposal was to get the number of interests in common with a single user.
For example, George has two interests in common with John. I'd like to get George's details and the total number of interests they have in common.

Comment: @IsaacFerreira I edited the answer. please try again